# Why contains(_ element: Element) seems to not exist for some element types?

Tags: arrays, swift4, contains

I'm trying to use Swift's `Array.contains(_ element: Element)` function, but it seems to exist only for arrays where `element` is of some (non complex) types.

For example, the following program in a Playground, produces the error `MyPlayground.playground:11:24: error: missing argument label 'where:' in call` (please note that it only fails on the **second** if)

```
class Robot {
}

class N10: Robot {
}

class Sphinx: Robot {
}

let robotNames = ["N10", "Sphinx"]
let robots: [Robot.Type] = [type(of: N10), type(of: Sphinx)]

if robotNames.contains("N10") {
    print("name is there")
}

if robots.contains(type(of: N10)) {
    print("type is there")
}
```

I'm aware of the `contains(where:)` method, but I just want to use the `contains(element:)` one.

The function's documentation does not seem to explain this either: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains

So my question is why the `contains(element:)` method only seems to be defined for some types of `element`. Or probably does `element` need to implement a specific protocol?

Comment: `element` must conform to `Equatable`. `String` does, `Robot` does not.

Comment: Thanks @vadian Do you know if there is some documentation from Apple about this?

Comment: ⌃⌘-click on the *legal* `contains`. You will see the declaration. Scroll upward to the beginning of the `extension`. There is the constraint to `Equatable`. I recommend also to use always code completion in Xcode. In the *illegal* `contains` Xcode doesn't offer you to use `contains(_ element)`.